# Can't access mod_wsgi hosted python (bottle.py) app

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, bottle

### Here is my Problem:

I wrote a bottle.py application and runs it on my pc with the internal bottle.py webserver. Now i want to upload my application to my server and would like to run it there with apache2 + mod_wsgi I have created the following Files :

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/**000-default**

```
...  

WSGIDaemonProcess web user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /dem /var/www/vhosts/test.de/rbdemo/app.wsgi
WSGIProcessGroup web

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/test.de/rbdemo>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

/var/www/vhosts/test.de/rbdemo/**app.wsgi**

```
import sys, os

sys.path = ['/var/www/vhosts/test.de/rbdemo'] + sys.path
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

from web import default_app # This loads your application

application = default_app()
```

And in my application:

/var/www/vhosts/test.de/rbdemo/**web.py**

```
from bottle import TEMPLATE_PATH, request, redirect, route, hook, run, default_app, jinja2_template as template, static_file

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(reloader=True)
```

### Apache LOG

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_AcquireThread: NULL new thread state
[Wed Mar 27 17:26:47 2013] [notice] child pid 10124 exit signal Aborted (6)
Fatal Python error: PyEval_AcquireThread: NULL new thread state
[Wed Mar 27 17:29:13 2013] [notice] child pid 18003 exit signal Aborted (6)
Fatal Python error: PyEval_AcquireThread: NULL new thread state
[Wed Mar 27 17:30:47 2013] [notice] child pid 10126 exit signal Aborted (6)
Fatal Python error: PyEval_AcquireThread: NULL new thread state
[Wed Mar 27 17:32:32 2013] [notice] child pid 21774 exit signal Aborted (6)
Fatal Python error: PyEval_AcquireThread: NULL new thread state
[Wed Mar 27 17:32:37 2013] [notice] child pid 21779 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Wed Mar 27 17:59:17 2013] [error] [client 118.139.160.196] client sent HTTP/1.1 request without hostname (see RFC2616 section 14.23): /w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.DFind:)
```

But if I want to access my application (demo.test.de) I get a 403 Forbidden Error...

Any Ideas ?

Thank you.

Comment: Might want to take out the hostname in your code "sys.path = ..." ;) Never know whos looking!

Comment: The number of things going on here are many... if you could better test and isolate a specific part of the problem we could be of more help :)

Comment: This might help you to solve the issue.   
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31887499/5203702