# Complex Python Bottle App + WSGI

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, bottle

I have a python bottle application inside of a single folder that's been organized by function and I would like to convert my existing cherrypy usage over to apache mod_wsgi.

The folder structure looks like the following:

```
- project
-- app.py (loads the webserver class and runs it)
-- app
--- common
--- logs
--- modules
--- tools
--- web
---- webserver.py
```

The reason for this structure was so code from common could be used within tools and web without any issue. Imports are all done in a style of "from app.common.blah import utility". When trying to setup mod_wsgi, it expects to load up a simple application.

Is it possible to run mod_wsgi with a folder structure like this? If not, are there any recommendations for setting up a structure that will allow for mod_wsgi, but also the sharing of common utilities between folders like tools and web?

Comment: The below approach solved my problem :  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31887499/5203702

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bottle deployment docs on Deployment](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html#server-options):

> All you need is an app.wsgi file that provides an application object. This object is used by mod_wsgi to start your application and should be a WSGI-compatible Python callable.
>
> File `/var/www/yourapp/app.wsgi`:

```
import os
# Change working directory so relative paths (and template lookup) work again
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

import bottle
# ... build or import your bottle application here ...
# Do NOT use bottle.run() with mod_wsgi
application = bottle.default_app()
```

In your case, edit the snippet above to import the application object that is presumably defined in your `app.py`

Comment: They would also need to set the Python module search path to include the directory '…./project'. If this is not done it will not be able to find the 'app' package.